# Compute the integral of $x^2\cos(x^2-xy)$ over the triangle $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)$

Tags: integration

The integral in question is $$\int_0^1\int_y^1x^2\cos(x^2-xy)\,dx\,dy$$

By Fubini's Theorem, we switch the order of integration and we obtain $$\int_0^1\int_0^xx^2\cos(x^2-xy)\,dy\,dx$$

The antiderivative in the $y$ direction is easy to compute and we get $$\int_0^1-x\sin(x^2-xy)\bigg|^x_0\,dx$$
$$=\int_0^1x\sin(x^2)\,dx$$
Which is another easy antiderivative
$$\frac{-\cos(x^2)}{2}\Bigg|_0^1=-\frac{\cos(1)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$$

I am not sure if the use of Fubini's is actually justified (I simply assumed it) but I think the steps I took are correct and reasonable.

Comment: What is your question, specifically? Is it whether you properly applied Fubini's Theorem?

Comment: @Peter: Compare to [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BIntegrate%5Bx%5E2+Cos%5Bx%5E2+-+x+y%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+y%2C+1%7D%5D%2C+%7By%2C+0%2C+1%7D%5D) - something seems wrong, symbolically, the result is $\sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$. Approach is correct, integration result has issue, look at that again. Integration result is $-\frac{1}{2} \cos \left(x^2\right)$

Comment: Note: I am just commenting on the double integration result - did not check setup.

Comment: @onetoinfinity The question specifically is if I correctly evaluated the integral using logical steps.

Comment: @Moo Thanks for the catch. After revision, I did not get that symbolic answer but I did get a numerical answer good to 6 digits.

Comment: Some Trig identities will help give the result I showed in comments (you show it in expanded form) - I did not check triangle setup and such - so you still need to verify of double integral correct.

Comment: Indeed $\sin^2(1/2)=1/2-\cos(1)/2$

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks good here. Your use of Fubini's Theorem is justified, and your final answer is correct, as can be verified from a common double-angle formula when $x=1/2$.

\begin{align}
&\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2x\\[0.5ex]
\implies&\sin^2x=\frac{1}{2}\Big(1-\cos(2x)\Big)
\end{align}